# Getting a TypeError: Required argument 'rec' (pos 2) not found

Tags: opencv, streamlit

MY code is as

```
sample = images[0].permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy()
    boxes = outputs[0]['boxes'].data.cpu().numpy()
    scores = outputs[0]['scores'].data.cpu().numpy()
    boxes = boxes[scores >= detection_threshold].astype(np.int32)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(32, 16))
    for box in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(img=sample,
                      pt1=(box[0], box[1]),
                      pt2=(box[2], box[3]),
                      color=(220, 0, 0))

ax.set_axis_off()
img = np.array(img)
st.image(cv2.UMat.get(sample), clamp=True)
st.write("# Results")
st.dataframe(pd.DataFrame(results))
```

BUt getting error as

```
TypeError: Required argument 'rec' (pos 2) not found
Traceback:
File "/home/stark/anaconda3/envs/mark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 332, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/stark/streamlit/streamlit.py", line 129, in <module>
    color=(220, 0, 0))
```

I am trying to deploy my model in streamlit and this is the last place I am stuck on

Comment: please check the data types of box[0], box[1]... they must be python ints. I see that you're already converting them to np.int32. try `int(box[0])`.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I tried but It gave the same error

Comment: another idea: try the call with positional arguments only, i.e. not named arguments. looks like whatever dispatch is happening gets confused and picks the wrong C++ signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did solve

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 8))
sample = sample.copy()
for box in boxes:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
    cv2.rectangle(sample,
                  (x1, y1),
                  (x2, y2),
                  (220, 0, 0), 2)


ax.set_axis_off()
```

Thanks, @christoph, your idea did work